# How are Futures in Scala evaluated, computed

Tags: scala, jvm, future

I was thinking, how are `Future`s being evaluated? I mean if we have imperative style programming where we execute program from point A to point B and somewhere between them we create a `Future` which, when completed, prints the result to the console. How is our program making this *step back* in flow to print it?

Comment: Google has a lot of resources on Futures and how they work — didn't you find anything? Also, Futures are best used not with callbacks but a higher level concept called composition.

Answer (score 1):

Futures are run on an ExecutionContext which is essentially a threadpool. When you create a Future block or use the various composition and callback methods (map, foreach, onComplete etc) on a future there is an implicit execution context passed along where the logic will be executed.

In a imperative program this will be roughly the same as just pushing a Runnable that would print onto the console onto a threadpool.

There is a good introduction here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

The most useful thing about futures is not using them imperatively though, but instead composing using map and flatMap to create chains of futures.

Comment: Fun fact: Futures in 2.10 [were implemented](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.0/#scala.Responder) via [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), though this is changed in 2.11